# Opencv2 Errors when trying to start a camera feed

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am getting an error stating " TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat' " from OpenCV when I run this part of my code:

```
# Enable camera
    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2) #cv2 will use Camera 0 (Default camera), in this case is the Raspberry Pi camera

   
        
    #Set Capture Frame
    frame = cap.read()
        
    #Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        
    cap.set(3, 640) # Setting the Height,
    cap.set(4, 420) # and Width of the capture
```

This is the Only part of the code to do with the camera (as of now)

After running the code, I was expecting to get a Window giving me a live feed from the camera. Instead I got the error.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

16/09/23 Update:

I have discovered a solution to part of my problem: The updated code is as follows:

```
    # Enable camera
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #cv2 will use Camera 0 (Default camera), in this case is the Raspberry Pi camera
        
        #Set Capture Frame
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
                
        #Display the frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        
        cap.set(3, 640) # Setting the Height,
        cap.set(4, 420) # and Width of the capture

    else:
        print (type(cap), "An Error Has occurred.")
```

From this I am getting a new error from the else statement, which to me means that the camera/live feed isn't opening in a window?

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)